# Why is there no boost::filesystem::move_file?

Tags: c++, file-io, boost-filesystem

I'm using boost filesystem to replace windows C++ functions like CopyFile and MoveFile to get some kind of portability between windows and linux. I'm using copy_file but I have not been able to find anything that moves files like a 'move_file' function. Do boost have a move file function?

I would very much prefer to use boost, but alternative suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's called `rename`, see [the manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename). Like the corresponding OS functions, this might or might not work if the source and destination paths are on different file systems. If it doesn't work, use a copy operation followed by a delete operation.

Comment: I confess that reading the manual and then in turn reading the ISO C page referred to by the manual, I don't see anything explicitly stating that the destination can be a file in another directory in order to move the file from one directory to another.  A careful reading implies that this is possible, but I think the boost documentation would be much more useful and more clear if it stated this possibility explicitly.  Boost documentation ticket: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9643

Comment: move (as mv under Linux) works across different filesystem while rename does not.

Answer (score -6):

```
void add_time(ptime& gen_time, int seconds) {
    boost::posix_time::millisec_posix_time_system_config::time_duration_type time_elapse(0, 0, seconds);
    //time_elapse = p2 - p1;
    gen_time = gen_time + time_elapse;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is the correct answer, but for some other question.